# Multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for a single store at same time

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data, apple-watch, nspersistentstore

I am developing iWatch app for my application. Now i had coded it so that the core-data store(sqlite file) is in shared group folder so that i can access data in iWatch extension, today's extension and share photo extension too.
Now i had created a new object of NSPersistentStoreCoordinator in iWatch extension but the problem is that the changes made by iPhone app while iWatch is open are not shown in the iWatch till i re-run the IWatch application.
Any idea what is the problem.

Comment: The watch app is neither resetting or initializing a new MOC, nor is it re-fetching from the store.  So the watch MOC is stale.

Comment: What is an iWatch? I want one! Like those old iTouch devices of lore...